# Cancel BackgroundWorker from outside the DoWork

Tags: c#

I want to cancel the BackgroundWorker outside the DoWork, i have beed trying to find a answer but i can't find the way, im out of arrows, any help will be apreciatted

```
private void Bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    HeavyWork();
}

private void HeavyWork()
{
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in XX.Rows)
    {
       if (!Bw1.CancellationPending)
                {
                  //DoThings
                }
        else
                {
                 //CANCEL
                }
    }  
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have written? You can call cancel on `Bw1` which will make it's `CancelationPending` Property true and it will stop your loop

Comment: Thanks man, i wasn't seeing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel it from your UI thread for example, just call:

```
Bw1.CancelAsync();
```

Your worker thread will know about it when it next executes:

```
if (!Bw1.CancellationPending)
```

You might want to change your worker thread code from:

```
private void HeavyWork()
{
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in XX.Rows)
    {
       if (!Bw1.CancellationPending)
       {
           //DoThings
       }
       else
       {
           //CANCEL
       }
    }  
}
```

...to:

```
private void HeavyWork()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in XX.Rows)
    {
       if (Bw1.CancellationPending)
                {
                  break;
                }

        // do things
    }  
}
```

...so that it exits the loop sooner